# How can I access a file saved in an ASP.NET Web API project and deployed on Azure cloud

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, path, filestream

There is a file I saved directly onto my ASP.NET Web API project that I need to access in one of my actions. I'm able to access the file and convert it to a stream when run locally, but after deploying to the cloud, I keep getting this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
> Could not find file 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\myfile.docx".

Can I find the file somewhere in `wwwroot` maybe? It is saved in my Web API project, which does not have the `...site\wwwroot\...` structure. This problem only occurs when the application is deployed to Azure.

I've tried the below but no luck.

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory + myfile.docx
```

and also

```
(string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("ContentRootPath") + myfile.docx
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the path simply the filename；
Following codes which create and read file works for me.

```
        [HttpGet("write")]
        public void write()
        {
            var path = Path.Combine("MyTest.txt");

            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(path))
            {
                byte[] content = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Hello World");

                fs.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            }
        }
        [HttpGet("read")]
        public string read()
        {
            string text= System.IO.File.ReadAllText("MyTest.txt");
            return text;
        }
```

Test
Create file
[image]
[image]
Read file
[image]

Path like "test/MyTest.txt" also works. But you need to prepare "test" folder when create file.